# Drupal or Umbraco: which is easiest for a junior dev/designer to come to terms with?

Tags: drupal, umbraco

Out of Drupal and Umbraco, in your opinion which CMS would be easiest for a junior dev / designer to come to terms with?

Initial configuration will be by an experienced developer, with handover to an in-house junior. I'm not a programmer, so forgive my terminology - but is one built using a more common language than the other, for instance? Are there particular traps / benefits of each one? Also, which one has a more active developer community?

I realise it's really hard to do this if you haven't worked in both, but I'd really appreciate any thoughts to help with choosing between these two systems - both of which meet our stated business requirements.

Thanks so much for your help,

V

Comment: You might want to ask your junior developer what language he is most comfortable in, as both the CMS choices use two very different languages.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, ideally you should leave this decision up to the developer in question. As choosing a CMS based on their choice of language will cut down development time considerably.

The *strongest* trait Drupal brings onto the table, is the fact that it has been around for quite some time and has a huge community supporting it. Its choices/options of modules are also very extensive as this would be a good point to factor into your decision. The documentation and guides that are available freely on the net may also aid your junior developer.

Just my 2 cents.